# How do I assign the results of the rename command to a variable?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rename

i am trying to set the output of a command to a variable in a script. i have searched all day and it looks like i have the command right. but each time i run my script, it just runs the command instead of only assigning it to a variable and not running it.

here is the relevant part of the script:

```
ffname=$(rename 's/_1080p_12000//' *.*)
echo $ffname
```

i need to use ffname as a variable in another part of the script without running the command.. but it doesnt seem to wanna work. anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `rename` on ubuntu doesn't output anything unless -v is used. It's better to avoid rename altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `-n`(no-act) option to `rename` to get the output.

```
ffnames=($(rename -n 's/_1080p_12000//' *.* | awk '{print $1,$NF}'))
```

The result contains multiple items. So you need a array to hold them.

Then do real renaming without `-n` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bash, you can use the [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) substitution operator on a populated variable to replace the portion of the filename that you want to delete. For example:

```
$ ffname=foo_1080p_12000.bar
$ echo "${ffname/_1080p_12000}"
foo.bar
```

However, it will remain up to you to perform the actual mv or rename commands, or to re-assign the modified value back to *ffname* if you like.